# Dynamically added form elements hides other elements until resize

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a form with a button that when clicked adds a new input to the form.

While the input is added, the form does not expand so that any contend below the added form is no longer visible, however the form resizes and all content is viewable if a user resizes their window.

See below

[image: Screen-Recording-2021-04-27-at-3.56.35-PM.gif]

Is this a CSS issue? If so what elements could it possibly be?

The HTML

```
<div id="single-form-next-prev" class="multisteps-form__panel shadow p-4 rounded bg-white" data-animation="scaleIn">
    <h3 class="text-center multisteps-form__title">Skills</h3>
        <div id="form-content-1" class="multisteps-form__content">
             <div id="input-grp-single-1" class="form-row mt-4">
                  <div class="col-12"><input class="form-control multisteps-form__input" type="text" placeholder="Skill 1"></div>
                   </div>
                            <br>
            <button id='addButton' class="btn btn-outline-primary text-truncate float-none float-sm-none add-another-btn" data-bss-hover-animate="pulse" type="button">Add Skill<i class="fas fa-plus-circle edit-icon"></i></button>
            <div id="next-prev-buttons" class="button-row d-flex mt-4"><button class="btn btn btn-primary js-btn-prev" type="button" title="Prev">Prev</button><button class="btn btn btn-primary ml-auto js-btn-next" type="button" title="Next">Find Results</button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
let id = 1;

$('#addButton').click(function() {

    $('#input-grp-single-'+id).after('<div id="input-grp-single-'+(id+1)+'" class="form-row mt-4"> <div class="col-12"><input class="form-control multisteps-form__input" type="text" placeholder="Skill '+(id+1)+'"></div></div>');
    id++;
});

});
```

The CSS

```
.multisteps-form__form {
   position: relative;
 }

.multisteps-form__panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.multisteps-form__panel.js-active {
   height: auto;
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}

.multisteps-form__panel[data-animation="scaleIn"] {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
 }

 .multisteps-form__panel[data-animation="scaleIn"].js-active {
   transition-property: all;
   transition-duration: 0.2s;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
   transition-delay: 0s;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
  }
```

Codepen link added
https://codepen.io/jdog6652/pen/ExZJvaQ

Comment: It'll be easier if you create the example in codepen, so we can see the functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much @Spectric and jc.vargas.valencia for taking the time, here is the codeine link as requested
https://codepen.io/jdog6652/pen/ExZJvaQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `overflow-hidden` class on your `#multple-step-form-n` element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let id = 1;
  $('[data-bss-hover-animate]')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      elem.addClass('animated ' + elem.attr('data-bss-hover-animate'))
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      elem.removeClass('animated ' + elem.attr('data-bss-hover-animate'))
    });

  $('#addButton').click(function() {

    $('#input-grp-single-' + id).after('<div id="input-grp-single-' + (id + 1) + '" class="form-row mt-4"> <div class="col-12"><input class="form-control multisteps-form__input" type="text" placeholder="Skill ' + (id + 1) + '"></div></div>');
    id++;
  });

});
//DOM elements
const DOMstrings = {
  stepsBtnClass: 'multisteps-form__progress-btn',
  stepsBtns: document.querySelectorAll(`.multisteps-form__progress-btn`),
  stepsBar: document.querySelector('.multisteps-form__progress'),
  stepsForm: document.querySelector('.multisteps-form__form'),
  stepsFormTextareas: document.querySelectorAll('.multisteps-form__textarea'),
  stepFormPanelClass: 'multisteps-form__panel',
  stepFormPanels: document.querySelectorAll('.multisteps-form__panel'),
  stepPrevBtnClass: 'js-btn-prev',
  stepNextBtnClass: 'js-btn-next'
};


//remove class from a set of items
const removeClasses = (elemSet, className) => {

  elemSet.forEach(elem => {

    elem.classList.remove(className);

  });

};

//return exect parent node of the element
const findParent = (elem, parentClass) => {

  let currentNode = elem;

  while (!currentNode.classList.contains(parentClass)) {
    currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
  }

  return currentNode;

};

//get active button step number
const getActiveStep = elem => {
  return Array.from(DOMstrings.stepsBtns).indexOf(elem);
};

//set all steps before clicked (and clicked too) to active
const setActiveStep = activeStepNum => {

  //remove active state from all the state
  removeClasses(DOMstrings.stepsBtns, 'js-active');

  //set picked items to active
  DOMstrings.stepsBtns.forEach((elem, index) => {

    if (index <= activeStepNum) {
      elem.classList.add('js-active');
    }

  });
};

//get active panel
const getActivePanel = () => {

  let activePanel;

  DOMstrings.stepFormPanels.forEach(elem => {

    if (elem.classList.contains('js-active')) {

      activePanel = elem;

    }

  });

  return activePanel;

};

//open active panel (and close unactive panels)
const setActivePanel = activePanelNum => {

  //remove active class from all the panels
  removeClasses(DOMstrings.stepFormPanels, 'js-active');

  //show active panel
  DOMstrings.stepFormPanels.forEach((elem, index) => {
    if (index === activePanelNum) {

      elem.classList.add('js-active');

      setFormHeight(elem);

    }
  });

};

//set form height equal to current panel height
const formHeight = activePanel => {

  const activePanelHeight = activePanel.offsetHeight;

  DOMstrings.stepsForm.style.height = `${activePanelHeight}px`;

};

const setFormHeight = () => {
  const activePanel = getActivePanel();

  formHeight(activePanel);
};

//STEPS BAR CLICK FUNCTION
DOMstrings.stepsBar.addEventListener('click', e => {

  //check if click target is a step button
  const eventTarget = e.target;

  if (!eventTarget.classList.contains(`${DOMstrings.stepsBtnClass}`)) {
    return;
  }

  //get active button step number
  const activeStep = getActiveStep(eventTarget);

  //set all steps before clicked (and clicked too) to active
  setActiveStep(activeStep);

  //open active panel
  setActivePanel(activeStep);
});

//PREV/NEXT BTNS CLICK
DOMstrings.stepsForm.addEventListener('click', e => {

  const eventTarget = e.target;

  //check if we clicked on `PREV` or NEXT` buttons
  if (!(eventTarget.classList.contains(`${DOMstrings.stepPrevBtnClass}`) || eventTarget.classList.contains(`${DOMstrings.stepNextBtnClass}`))) {
    return;
  }

  //find active panel
  const activePanel = findParent(eventTarget, `${DOMstrings.stepFormPanelClass}`);

  let activePanelNum = Array.from(DOMstrings.stepFormPanels).indexOf(activePanel);

  //set active step and active panel onclick
  if (eventTarget.classList.contains(`${DOMstrings.stepPrevBtnClass}`)) {
    activePanelNum--;

  } else {

    activePanelNum++;

  }

  setActiveStep(activePanelNum);
  setActivePanel(activePanelNum);

});

//SETTING PROPER FORM HEIGHT ONLOAD
window.addEventListener('load', setFormHeight, false);

//SETTING PROPER FORM HEIGHT ONRESIZE
window.addEventListener('resize', setFormHeight, false);

//changing animation via animation select !!!YOU DON'T NEED THIS CODE (if you want to change animation type, just change form panels data-attr)

const setAnimationType = newType => {
  DOMstrings.stepFormPanels.forEach(elem => {
    elem.dataset.animation = newType;
  });
};

//selector onchange - changing animation
const animationSelect = document.querySelector('.pick-animation__select');
/* 

====NOTICE====
The block of code below was giving an error not related to the question, so it was commented out


animationSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const newAnimationType = animationSelect.value;

  setAnimationType(newAnimationType);
});
*/
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.multisteps-form__progress {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.multisteps-form__progress-btn {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: rgba(108, 117, 125, 0.7);
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .multisteps-form__progress-btn {
    text-indent: 0;
  }
}

.multisteps-form__progress-btn:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: all 0.15s linear 0s, -webkit-transform 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.05, 1.09, 0.16, 1.4) 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s linear 0s, transform 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.05, 1.09, 0.16, 1.4) 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s linear 0s, transform 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.05, 1.09, 0.16, 1.4) 0s, -webkit-transform 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.05, 1.09, 0.16, 1.4) 0s;
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 3;
}

.multisteps-form__progress-btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: calc(-50% - 13px / 2);
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  background-color: currentColor;
  z-index: 1;
}

.multisteps-form__progress-btn:first-child:after {
  display: none;
}

.multisteps-form__progress-btn.js-active {
  color: #007bff;
}

.multisteps-form__progress-btn.js-active:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1.2);
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1.2);
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.multisteps-form__form {
  position: relative;
}

.multisteps-form__panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.multisteps-form__panel.js-active {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.multisteps-form__panel[data-animation="scaleIn"] {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.multisteps-form__panel[data-animation="scaleIn"].js-active {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.edit-icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.add-another-btn {
  border: 2px solid #5C99C7;
  color: #5C99C7;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.add-another-btn:hover {
  border: 2px solid #5C99C7;
  background: #5C99C7;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<body style="background: var(--gray-dark);">
  <h1 class="text-center" style="color: var(--light);">Skill Finder</h1>
  <section>
    <div id="multple-step-form-n" class="container" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 57px;">
      <div id="progress-bar-button" class="multisteps-form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 ml-auto mr-auto mb-4">
            <div class="multisteps-form__progress"><a class="btn multisteps-form__progress-btn js-active" role="button" title="User Info">City</a><a class="btn multisteps-form__progress-btn" role="button" title="User Info">Skills</a><a class="btn multisteps-form__progress-btn" role="button"
                title="User Info">Results</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="multistep-start-row" class="row">
        <div id="multistep-start-column" class="col-12 col-lg-8 m-auto">
          <form id="main-form" class="multisteps-form__form">
            <div id="single-form-next" class="multisteps-form__panel shadow p-4 rounded bg-white js-active" data-animation="scaleIn">
              <h3 class="text-center multisteps-form__title">Enter your City</h3>
              <div id="form-content" class="multisteps-form__content">
                <div id="input-grp-single" class="form-row mt-4">
                  <div class="col-12"><input class="form-control multisteps-form__input" type="text" placeholder="City"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="next-button" class="button-row d-flex mt-4"><button class="btn btn btn-primary ml-auto js-btn-next" type="button" title="Next">Next</button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="single-form-next-prev" class="multisteps-form__panel shadow p-4 rounded bg-white" data-animation="scaleIn">
              <h3 class="text-center multisteps-form__title">Skills</h3>
              <div id="form-content-1" class="multisteps-form__content">
                <div id="input-grp-single-1" class="form-row mt-4">
                  <div class="col-12"><input class="form-control multisteps-form__input" type="text" placeholder="Skill 1"></div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button id='addButton' class="btn btn-outline-primary text-truncate float-none float-sm-none add-another-btn" data-bss-hover-animate="pulse" type="button">Add Skill<i class="fas fa-plus-circle edit-icon"></i></button>
                <div id="next-prev-buttons" class="button-row d-flex mt-4"><button class="btn btn btn-primary js-btn-prev" type="button" title="Prev">Prev</button><button class="btn btn btn-primary ml-auto js-btn-next" type="button" title="Next">Find Results</button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="single-form-next-prev-1" class="multisteps-form__panel shadow p-4 rounded bg-white" data-animation="scaleIn">
              <h3 class="text-center multisteps-form__title">Map</h3>
              <div id="form-content-2" class="multisteps-form__content">
                <div id="mapid"></div>
                <div id="next-prev-buttons-1" class="button-row d-flex mt-4"><button class="btn btn btn-primary js-btn-prev" type="button" title="Prev">Prev</button><button class="btn btn btn-primary ml-auto js-btn-next" type="button" title="Next">Next</button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution
Its weird that even if you resize the window smaller the hidden elements get shown again

Comment: @Marc-9 Glad to help :)